# When will my Google Apps Script email recipients per day limit increase?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, send, google-workspace, google-developer-tools

I am a G Suite user using Google Apps Scripts to trigger emails. [This link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) says that I can email 1500 recipients per day but that...

"newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users".

This means I can only send 100 emails per day, which I am nearing.

I want to know how many billing cycles I have to wait for until my send limit will increase. I am the only user of the G Suite domain and the vagueness in the above quote isn't helping me. If anyone knows the answer and/or can suggest a solution to increasing the send limit now or a clever solution to cope whilst the limit is at it's current level, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support question, not a programming question.

Comment: @SunilJindal See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Your question is better suited for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)